# What's the Angular equivalent of Vue <slot/>?

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, components

Example:

Parent component:

```
<div> 
  Hello <slot/>!
</div>
```

Child Component:

```
<div> 
  World 
</div>
```

App component:

```
<Parent> 
  <Child/> 
</Parent>
```

Output: Hello World!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We have something like this in Angular.

The directive `<ng-content>` is used to project outer content into the current component, and you can use a selector to project specific content with a CSS style query.

**app-example.html:**

```html
<div>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div>
   <ng-content selector=".child"></ng-content>
</div>
```

**app-component.html**

```html
<app-example>
   <span class="child">World</span>
   Hello
</app-example>
```

Renders this output:

```html
<app-example>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div><span class="child">World</span></div>
</app-example>
```

Comment: I had to use `<ng-content select=".child"></ng-content>` ("select" rather than "selector") to get this to work, as per [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691/).

Comment: Key difference between `ng-content` and Vue `<slot/>` is that Angular cannot use the parent slot content as a dynamic template; however with Vue `<slot/>` you to bind values in the parent slot content that the child component can use.

I've tried for months to do this in Angular so I can have a generic `data-table` component and customize the row content as needed. Seems that `ng-content/ng-template/ng-container` cannot do this.

I just made this work with Vue using a named `<slot/>` in under an hour and it works great.

If only I could get management to buy in to switching to Vue...

Comment: In Vue, slots can have default content to use as fallback when no content has been provided by the embedding container. However, ng-content must not have any content. That's just one of the major issues Angular's ng-content is having when compared with slots of Vue or web components in general.

Answer (score 2):

### Content Projection

In angular its called "Content Projection", and there are three types

**1) Single-slot content projection**
With this type of content projection, a component accepts content from a
single source.

Is content projection cool?

**2) Multi-slot content projection**


Is content projection cool?

Let's learn about content projection!

In this scenario, a component accepts content from multiple sources.

**3) Conditional content projection**
Components that use conditional content projection render content only
when specific conditions are met.

Source:
https://angular.io/guide/content-projection